# Unexpected function output when function parameter is negated

Tags: vhdl

I have a priority encoding function that returns a vector containing a `1` at the position where the first `1` is found in the input vector. The function works as expected, unless I try to negate the input vector. Here's an example that demonstrates the unexpected behavior:

---

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

entity tb IS
end tb;

architecture run of tb is
    constant N : natural := 5;

    function get_first_one_in_vec (vec_in: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
        variable ret: std_logic_vector(vec_in'high downto vec_in'low);
    begin
        ret := (others => '0');
        for i in vec_in'low to vec_in'high loop
            if vec_in(i)='1' then
                ret(i) := '1';
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop;

        return ret;
    end get_first_one_in_vec;

    signal a            : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    signal abar         : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);

    signal first_a      : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    signal first_nota   : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    signal first_abar   : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
begin
    process
    begin
        a <= "10100";
        wait for 10 ns;
        a <= "01011";
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

    abar        <= not(a);
    first_a     <= get_first_one_in_vec(a);
    first_nota  <= get_first_one_in_vec(not(a));
    first_abar  <= get_first_one_in_vec(abar);

end run;
```

---

To my understanding, `first_nota` should be the same as `first_abar`. However, my simulator (ModelSim - Intel FPGA Starter Edition 10.5b, rev. 2016.10) thinks otherwise, as you can see here:

[image]

---

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works OK:

```
function get_first_one_in_vec (vec_in: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
    variable ret: std_logic_vector(vec_in'length downto 1);
    variable inp: std_logic_vector(vec_in'length downto 1) := vec_in;
begin
    ret := (others => '0');
    for i in inp'right to inp'left loop
        if inp(i)='1' then
            ret(i) := '1';
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return ret;
end get_first_one_in_vec;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3zP_

Why does yours not work? Well, when you call your function with the `not` operator* as part of the expression:

```
first_nota  <= get_first_one_in_vec(not a);
```

the numbering of the input to the function is changed to `1 to` by the `not` operator. Why? Here is the code for the `not` operator and you can see why:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
-- not
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
FUNCTION "not"  ( l : std_logic_vector ) RETURN std_logic_vector IS
    -- pragma built_in SYN_NOT
-- pragma subpgm_id 204
    --synopsys synthesis_off
    ALIAS lv : std_logic_vector ( 1 TO l'LENGTH ) IS l;
    VARIABLE result : std_logic_vector ( 1 TO l'LENGTH ) := (OTHERS => 'X');
    --synopsys synthesis_on
BEGIN
    --synopsys synthesis_off
    FOR i IN result'RANGE LOOP
        result(i) := not_table( lv(i) );
    END LOOP;
    RETURN result;
    --synopsys synthesis_on
END;
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyway, this breaks your code (which starts scanning from the other end of the word).

One way of making function agnostic to the ordering of the numbering of its input is to normalise the inputs like this:

```
variable inp: std_logic_vector(vec_in'length downto 1) := vec_in;
```

Once you have done this, you're in control. So, instead of loops from `'high` `downto` `'low`, we can be more explicit and loop from `'right` `to` `'left`:

```
for i in inp'right to inp'left loop
```

---

- `not` is an *operator* not a *function*. You don't need the brackets.

Comment: ... you don't need brackets, unless you call it with function call notation:  "not"(A).   :).   What is interesting about this notation is that it qualifies as a conversion function and can be used on port maps (even prior to 2008).

Comment: It's a pity that I cannot accurately express my disgust on the way that `not` function is implemented. That is an outrageous piece of code. Thank you Matthew

Comment: I think your disgust may be misplaced. The implementation of `not` is not the problem: the issue is that *you* have made an implicit assumption in your code that "first" is equivalent to `vec_in'low`. It isn't: it's actually `vec_in'right`, which is what Matthew's code fixes. You're assuming that everybody in your system has pre-agreed that all vectors should have a `downto` range, and that never happens in practice. However, you can be pretty sure that everyone agrees that the bit on the right is the LS bit, which is where your priority encoder should start operation from.